# int object is not subscriptable in a loop

Tags: python

I'm making a simple loop where I check the length of the string of the int and then make 2 conditions, but the following error:

```
if len(str(valueOfCardPlayer[count])) == 1:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my code:

```
global valueOfCardPlayer
global suitOfCardPlayer
if not showAllCards:
    count = 0
    for eachCard in playerCards:
        valueOfCardPlayer = values[eachCard.split()[count]]
        suitOfCardPlayer = suitsSymbol[eachCard.split()[count + 2]]
        print(valueOfCardPlayer)


        if len(str(valueOfCardPlayer[count])) == 1:
            print(f"Player:\n\n"
                  f"------------\n"
                  f"| {valueOfCardPlayer[count]} {suitOfCardPlayer[count]}      |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|      {valueOfCardPlayer[count]} {suitOfCardPlayer[count]} |\n"
                  f"----------\n")
        else:
            print(f"Player:\n\n"
                  f"------------\n"
                  f"| {valueOfCardPlayer[count]} {suitOfCardPlayer[count]}     |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|          |\n"
                  f"|     {valueOfCardPlayer[count]} {suitOfCardPlayer[count]} |\n"
                  f"----------\n")
        count += 1
```

P.S.: The global variables are lists

Comment: What are the data types of the lists? I would assume `valueOfCardPlayer` is a list of integers, `suitOfCardPlayer` is a list of strings and `playerCards` is a list of string. But can you confirm this please?

Comment: Problem is your globals don't remain lists after the two lines following the `for` statement unless `values[eachCard.split()[count]]` is a list. It appears from the error message that it is an int.

Comment: @aafewfwefe values might be. however youu  are assigning `valueOfCardPlayer` to a value from that dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You first extract a value from your dictionary using key `eachCard.split()[count]`:

```
valueOfCardPlayer = values[eachCard.split()[count]]
```

You then attempt to index the resulting integer:

```
valueOfCardPlayer[count]
```

You cannot index an integer, so an error is expected. You are mistaken when you say all the global variables are lists of strings. This is not true: `valueOfCardPlayer` is assigned an integer value.

Comment: but I first transform the int into str in 
len(str(valueOfCardPlayer[count])) == 1

Comment: That doesn't matter, after `valueOfCardPlayer = values[eachCard.split()[count]]`, the variable `valueOfCardPlayer` is an `int`. You can't index an integer. `str` conversion occurs **after** indexing with `[count]`.

Comment: could I possibly put append instead of =?

Comment: @aafewfwefe, No.

Comment: what could I do then?

Comment: @aafewfwefe, You can create a **[mcve]** and ask a new question.